# PHP Refactoring Tool

Tags: php, refactoring

Is there any PHP refactoring tool that would transform a huge noodle code to a proper function based one?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do that automatized. Static analysis may reformat your code, eliminate bad practices or inform you about security vulnerabilities, but it can't turn your code into nice and clean OOP.

Comment: +1 If it was as simple as running a program to generate better code, there wouldn't be so much bad code out there.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: and ther facepalms/day ratio would be lower around the globe

Comment: There is Rector now, that is capable to handle it

Answer (score 3):

#### 2019+ answer

Nowadays you can use a tool called [Rector](https://getrector.org/) (I'm author of).

It uses `nikic/php-parser`, static analysis and node based rules. That means you can e.g. rename every case of function `strlen` to `Nette\Utils\Strings::length()`.

Or basically anything you want to. Many rules are supported from in the core code ([see Rector on Github](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector)), e.g. upgrade from PHP 5.2 throughout to 7.4.

But it can be configured to do what you want. It will take some thinking to determine how to detect what should be extracted and what not. If you can put the transformation into words as a human, it's possible to put that into PHP code so it will do everywhere in your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Studio (for Eclipse) has support for refactoring code - it allows you to select a piece of code and extract functions/methods. For example:

[image]

It also allows for renaming of variables to further clean up your code. While this is not a fully automated solution, it **will** significantly help you clean up the mess. Hope this helps.